# Different Methods of Solving Bernoulli Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The equation in question is: $\frac{dy}{dx} + y = y^2$.

I make the substitution: $v = y^{-1}$ and $v'=-y^{-2}$ .

This I believe gives a first order linear ODE: $-v'+v=1$

I think that this can be solved using an integrating factor of $e^x$, but I am having trouble solving it this way. Are there any other methods of solving the ODE by making that substitution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Amzoti yes its the second one. To solve by exact equation, would it require an integrating factor? I'm not sure if I'm using the right integrating factor.

Comment: I would be grateful if someone could also show how to solve using the IF as another method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ${\mathrm{d}x\over \mathrm{d}y} + y = y^2$.

Should that be: $\color{blue}{\mathrm{d}y\over \mathrm{d}x} + y = y^2$? $\color{red}{\text{(Check this.)}}$

> I make the substitution: $v = y^{-1},$ and: $v'=-y^{-2}$ .

That would be: $v' = -y^{-2} y'$  (derivation wrt x, rather than y, by the Chain Rule)

> This I believe gives a first order linear ODE: $-v'+v=1$

$y' + y = y^2 \implies -y^{-2}y' - y^{-1} = -1 \implies v' - v = -1$

> I think that this can be solved using an integrating factor of $e^x$, but I am having trouble solving it this way. Are there any other methods of solving the ODE by making that substitution? Thanks in advance.

Nah.  No integrating factor required here. Just a plain rearrangement.

$\begin{aligned}v' = -1 + v & \implies \int \frac{\mathrm{d} v}{-1+v} = \int \mathrm{d} x \\ ~ & \implies \ln(-1+v) = x + c & \text{for arbitrary constant } c \\ & \implies -1 + v = k e^x  & k = e^c \\ & \implies y^{-1} = k e^x + 1 \\ & \implies y = \dfrac{1}{k e^x + 1} \end{aligned}$

Comment: Could you explain how you got y' + y = -y^2 from the original problem? This is probably something so simple yet I am having trouble seeing where it came from.

Comment: could you point out where the negative came from that is on the right side? The original problem did not have a negative, and the only time I get one is when i make the substitution with v.

Comment: @user155060; typo